# Restrict menu item to certain roles in TB Mega Menu

Tags: 7, blocks, navigation

I am currently using TB Mega Menu on D7 to configure my main menu. One of the main menu item is accessible to both anon & authenticated users.I would like to have a block attached to this item as a drop down but it should be accessible only by certain roles - not all authenticated users. I have enabled block visibility restrictions for this block by the user roles I want. But I am still able to view this block as part of the menu as an anon user. How do I restrict this?

Comment: did you clear the cache?

Comment: yes I did clear the cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible workaround solution would be to create another menu all together and give the block menu access to the role that you need and exclude this role from your original menu.

Comment: I followed your idea and created another menu. The block is now only visible for the roles I need. Thanks!